# Semantic issue Incompatible block pointer

Tags: ios

i have changed the architectures to standard since the archive will not be accepted in itunes connect. I have an issue with one module, the code is here:

```
- (UIViewController *)modulePage:(NSString *)pageName params:(NSDictionary *)params {
    UIViewController *vc = nil;
    if ([pageName isEqualToString:LocalPathPageNameHome]) {
        vc = [[AboutTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutTableViewController" bundle:KGO_SHARED_RESOURCE_BUNDLE()];
    }
    else if ([pageName isEqualToString:LocalPathPageNameDetail]) {

        NSString *command = [params objectForKey:@"command"];
        if (command) {
            KGOWebViewController *webVC = [[KGOWebViewController alloc] init];
            webVC.title = [params stringForKey:@"title"];
            [webVC applyTemplate:@"common/fullscreenWebview.html"];

            KGORequest *request = [[KGORequestManager sharedManager] requestWithDelegate:nil
                                                                              module:@"about"
                                                                                path:command
                                                                             version:1
                                                                              params:nil];
            request.expectedResponseType = [NSString class];
            request.handler = ^(id jsonObject) {
                webVC.HTMLString = jsonObject;
                return 1;
            };
            [request connect];

            vc = webVC;
        }
    }

    return vc;
}
```

## pragma mark -

@end

the error is:

> Incompatible block pointer types assigning to 'JSONObjectHandler' (aka 'NSInteger (^)(__strong id)') from 'int (^)(__strong id)'

Any ideas..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
request.handler = ^NSInteger(id jsonObject) {
    webVC.HTMLString = jsonObject;
    return 1;
};
```

I.e. matching the return type for the provided block.